# Display amount of questions asked about [binary] in binary

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

[image]

I just noticed that the amount of questions asked in [binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/binary) is `11,111`, and I think it would be a nice [Easter Egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)) if that number was displayed in binary rather than decimal. This could be implemented for other related tags as well, such as [twos-complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twos-complement).

Comment: And it should be switched over in 33 days.

Comment: I have 10 conflicting opinions of this idea, 1 for and 1 against.

Comment: I would rather the developers use their time more wisely than implementing Easter eggs ...

Comment: If this was implemented, then the next idea would be showing the amount of questions asked about [tag:whitespace-language] in whitespaces...

Answer (score 4):

This seems like it might be kind of fun, but consider:

1. Stack Overflow has a limited number of developers. Which features would you rather they spend their time implementing? Easter eggs and UI gimmicks, or things that will actually improve the site in a concrete way for a large number of people?
2. Speaking of large numbers of people, the number of eyes on the [binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/binary) tag is rather small, and *especially* the number of people looking at "Questions tagged [binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/binary)." If this was a cute little game for the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag, it would still be a waste of time in my opinion, but at least it would be something that a large number of people would chuckle at for half a second.
3. Little Easter eggs like this *seem* cool, until you consider that each deviation of behavior and special-case becomes a potential support problem. Different people see different things depending on which tag they're looking at. It isn't discoverable, it isn't explainable, and it's extremely forgettable. Heck, I suspect a fair number of folks wouldn't even get the joke (at least, not without having it explained to them, and what's the fun in that). Is it really worth the possibility of breakage and aggravation just to have a few seconds worth of fun?

No, consistency is *paramount* in UX design.

Stack Overflow's development team *does* like to have a little bit of fun every year at April 1st ([April Fool's Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools%27_Day)). It is coming up soon; look forward to whatever they have in store. This works better because the fun *goes away* after that day is over. Nobody has to keep supporting it or answering questions about it. It also allows the pranks to be more elaborate. I'd rather have one big cool thing than a bunch of little tiny not-really-all-that-cool things.